# How can I interpret a windows dmp file analysis using Windbg?

Tags: windows-7, analysis, windbg

[I have uploaded the full debug output here.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/242829/debug.txt)

I've got a Windows 7 RTM 64 bit machine that is crashing intermittently and I managed to load the correct symbols and get what seems to be a proper analysis. I don't know where to go from here or go about fixing the problem since it seems to be blaming it on tcpip.sys. Although I don't really know how to read this output, the following excerpts from the WinDBG seem relevant:

```
CURRENT_IRQL:  2
    
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff80000b9c058 -- (.exr
 0xfffff80000b9c058)
ExceptionAddress: fffff80002abb2b6 (nt!RtlEnumerateEntryHashTable+0x0000000000000080)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
tcpip!IppFlushNeighborSet+ba
fffff880`0186e22a 4885c0          test
rax,rax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  8

SYMBOL_NAME: 
tcpip!IppFlushNeighborSet+ba

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: tcpip

IMAGE_NAME:  tcpip.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc26e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 
X64_0x1E_tcpip!IppFlushNeighborSet+ba

BUCKET_ID: 
X64_0x1E_tcpip!IppFlushNeighborSet+ba
```

Answer (score 2):

For a really quick high level information set try:

!analyze -v

This will give you a bunch of related information, including a detailed stack trace.

The windows team blogs are pretty useful resources, the article at the link below goes into some good detail on what this particular command does:

[Debug 101: What does !analyze do? - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/debug-101-what-does-analyze-do/ba-p/374111)

Also check the NTDebugging blog for extremely detailed articles.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'tcpip.sys' can be using a buggy network driver. Try to uninstall it (or them) and see what happens.

Also it can be buggy itself: with proprietary software you never know what is really happening :) But at the first glance `Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff` is very strange: looks like pointer arithmetics error.

To read the output, you need to know WinAPI. Try to Google for the functions you meet: like `IppFlushNeighborSet()`. This can help you to understand what's happening, and maybe it'll point on something.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the windbg help file (.chm) is a very helpful tool for figuring out how to approach debugging a kernel dump. http://www.dumpanalysis.org/ is another helpful place to look.

You are going to want to look at the stack (at a minimum) and see if you can walk the tcpip.sys image back.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/) for some excellent tutorials by a WinDBG expert.

[WinDbg / SOS Cheat Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024041713/http://geekswithblogs.net/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx)